# In C#, what is the best way to convert a List<T> to a SortedDictionary<string, T>?

Tags: c#, collections, sorteddictionary

I have a list of SpecialEvent objects in a list

```
List<SpecialEvent>
```

and i want to convert it to a sorted dictionary where the key is the SpecialEvent.Date and the value is the SpecialEvent object

I basically want something like:

```
list.ToDictionary(r=>r.Date, r=>r)
```

but that converts to sorted dictionary instead of a regular one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the constructor of `SortedDictionary`:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, SpecialEvent>(list.ToDictionary(r => r.Date, r => r));
```

Or, as a generic method:

```
public static SortedDictionary<T1,T2> ToSortedDictionary<Tin,T1,T2>(this List<Tin> source, Func<Tin,T1> keyselector, Func<Tin,T2> valueselector)
{
    return new SortedDictionary<T1,T2>(source.ToDictionary(keyselector, valueselector));
}
```

Comment: This first builds up an entire `Dictionary<,>` based on hash codes, only to create another object, the `SortedDictionary<,>` which is of corse based on `IComparable<>`, and the first `Dictionary<,>` is then discarded again. It will work (except in hypothetical situations where `GetHashCode` and `Equals` do not "separate" instances that are considered different by `CompareTo`) but Lee's answer seems more elegant.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> seq, Func<TValue, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach(TValue item in seq)
    {
        dict.Add(keySelector(item), item);
    }

    return dict;
}
```

then you can use it as

```
SortedDictionary<DateTime, SpecialEvent> sortedEvents = list.ToSortedDictionary(r => r.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `SortedDictionary` does not support duplicate keys. If you have two or more events with the same date you'll end up with an `ArgumentException` saying: *An entry with the same key already exists.*

A better approach is therefore probably to just sort your list of events:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => a.Date.CompareTo(b.Date));
```

This will perform an efficient in-place quick sort of your events. The result is that the list of events is sorted by date in ascending order.